# Retrieve oracle sid from oratab file

Tags: shell, sed, oracle11g, ksh

I'm creating this ksh shell script to compare Oracle homes from two database name which user inputs.

I tried using `cat` and also `sed` from various threads but somehow not able to put oracle home value into variable to compare them.

```
Oratab:
db1:/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3:Y
db2:/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3:N
#db3:/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4:Y

Runtime:
./compare_db db1 db2

#!/bin/ksh
sid1=$1;
sid2=$2;
file=/etc/oratab


function compare  {

 home1= sed -n "s#${sid1}.*/\(.*\)${sid1}.*#\1#p" $file
 home2= sed -n "s#${sid2}.*/\(.*\)${sid2}.*#\1#p" $file

if $home1 = $home2; then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure"
fi
}

Output: (I don't want to include last part "N/Y" after the : (colon))
home1 = /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3
home2 = /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3
db1 = db2
success
```

Obviously above is not working and only test code, does somebody comment and what's missing or how it can be done in elegant way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it elegantly with this combination of programs :

```
home1=$(grep $sid1 $file | cut -d":" -f2) --> output /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3
home2=$(grep $sid2 $file | cut -d":" -f2) --> output /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3
```

grep --> finds the line in which the specified SID is

cut  --> cuts the second field (specified by -f2), fields are delimited with the specified character -d":"

Comment: Thank you ivanzg works perfectly fine and looks short and simple.

Comment: How can we not list db2 if it starts from comment (#)

Comment: You can use this for example : home1=$(grep -v "#" $file | grep $sid1 $file | cut -d":" -f2)

Comment: Correction for above comment : home1=$(grep -v "#" $file | grep $sid1 | cut -d":" -f2)

Answer (score 2):

awk works:

```
awk -F: "/^${mysid}/{printf \"%s\n\",\$2}" /etc/oratab
```